# How to define x:Key for resource in one place and use it in XAML and code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

Question in title pretty much sums it up. I have some resource object defined in XAML and I'd like to access it in code behind also. So is there a way to define x:Key for it at one place instead of hard coding x:Key (as string) in both XAML and code behind?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to write the x:Key="STRING" in the XAML and then once again in the FindResource ("STRING") in code behind, you want some way to create it once and protect yourself from having to make key changes in two palces?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to not have to code up the string twice you can store it as a static variable, here I've put it in App.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string Key1 = "testKey";
}
```

When you want to use this key in a resource for your app you can do so like this.

```
<Application.Resources>        
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static local:App.Key1}"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

And in C# you no longer need to use the exact string name because it's in App

```
var brush = FindResource(App.Key1);
```

To use the resource in XAML you use

```
<TextBox Background="{StaticResource {x:Static local:App.Key1}}"
```

Comment: +1 for a clever and specific answer to the question; this does indeed move the string definition to a single place. I wonder, though, what it does for XAML loading performance, whether the approach is useful in a `DataTemplate` or `Style`, and whether it works in `Triggers`.

Comment: Honestly, I've never tried it. Only posted because I was curious to see if it could be done. I think it requires more code than just simply putting the strings in. There is no intellisense in the XAML editor so it doesn't really help.

Comment: Hey this works great, just tested it. I never thought of using statics. Works with DataTemplate and Style Setters/Triggers. Thanks!

Comment: np, surprised no one jumped on me for using the term "static variable" lol :D

Comment: I'd declare `Key1` as `publiс const string`, of course it won't reduce memory consumption so much, but why not making code slightly cleaner? :)

Comment: You can use nameof to get rid of the string completely!  `public partial class App : Application
{
    public const string TestKey = nameof(TestKey);
}`

Answer (score 2):

In XAML you would reference it like:

```
{StaticResource myResource}
```

In code-behind you would use the [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) method.

Comment: Culd you provide more details? How did you define myResource?